# Airflow DAGs disabled automatically?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

What might cause our Airflow (Airflow 1.10.9 and MariaDB: 10.4.15) DAGs to disable suddenly? We noticed that many of our dags were disabled automatically without human intervention.

[image]

Comment: Check the logs there is an event for is_paused. You can find when it happened and by who.

Comment: @Elad I didn't see any weird disabled events occurred. Where do all these is_paused values store?